# Exercise from A First Journey through Logic

Tags: set-theory, solution-verification, ordinals

1.11.1. *Prove that ${\omega}^2=\omega \omega$ is not of the form $\delta + \omega$ for some ordinal $\delta$.*

This is one of the exercises in the book "A First Journey through Logic". I tried to prove it, but I am not sure about that. If someone give me a feedback about the proof, it would be really helpful.

*Proof.* Suppose not. Since $\omega$ is a limit ordinal, by the properties of ordinal addition and multiplication, we obtain $\bigcup_{\beta < \omega }\delta + \beta =\delta + \omega = \omega \omega= \bigcup_{\alpha < \omega}\omega \alpha$ .

Now, taking $\beta =0$, we get $\delta < \omega \alpha $ for some $\alpha < \omega $ . Since $\omega \alpha $ is a limit ordinal (this is the first part of the exercise), we get $\delta + \gamma < \omega \alpha $ for all $\gamma <\omega$. Since $\alpha<\omega$ implies $\omega\alpha<\omega \omega$, we conclude that $ \delta + \omega \leq \omega \alpha < \omega \omega = \delta + \omega $. This contradiction finishes the proof.

P.S. This is my first question in this website. If you have any suggestion about my writing, please let me know.

Comment: It would be better to start the last paragraph by observing that $\delta<\omega\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\omega$: as you’ve written it, you’re talking about some completely undefined $\beta$. Taking $\beta=0$ avoids that problem. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: I understand what you mean, thanks. I thought that since $\delta + \beta$ is a proper subset of the first union, this is an element of that union. Thus, it will be also an element of the other union. That's why I wrote like that. But I admit that this is better with your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: You’re welcome. The problem is that $\delta+\beta$ is a proper subset of the first union **only** if you define $\beta$ to be a finite ordinal, and you left it undefined: the use of $\beta$ as index variable in the union doesn’t give it a value. You could pick any $n\in\omega$ for $\beta$, but the simplest is $0$.

Comment: Now, I definitely understand my mistake, thank you for your interest.

Comment: You’re welcome.